# Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree in c

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

**I want to convert sorted 1-D array to Binary Search Tree, but I am not getting the desired output with this code:**

```
int arr[7] = {-10,-3,-1,0,3,7,9};

typedef struct tree{
   int data;
   struct tree *left;
   struct tree *right;
}bst;

struct tree *CreateNode(int data){
   bst *node = (bst*)malloc(sizeof(bst));
   node->data = data;
   node->left = NULL;
   node->right = NULL;
   return node;
}
struct tree *BST(bst *root,int start,int end){
    if(start>end){
        return NULL;
    }
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    root = CreateNode(arr[mid]);
    BST(root->left,start,mid-1);
    // printf("%d\n",root->data);
    BST(root->right,mid+1,end);
    return root;
 }
```

Comment: So much information is missing from this question. And then there's the fact that two sentences you did include seem to talk about completely different things. You have failed to communicate what you are attempting to do and to demonstrate the problem you are facing.

Comment: 1) Create an insert function. 2) Call it for every element in the list.

Comment: @ikegami I want to convert sorted 1-D array to binary search tree

Comment: That's neither of the things the question states! Fix your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the pointer, otherwise you alter the value of a local pointer, this should work:

```
struct tree *BST(bst **root,int start,int end){
    if(start>end){
        return NULL;
    }
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    *root = CreateNode(arr[mid]);
    BST(&((*root)->left),start,mid-1);
    //printf("%d\n",(*root)->data);
    BST(&((*root)->right),mid+1,end);
    return *root;
}
```

or as pointed out by @JohBollinger, instead of passing a pointer to the node, use the `return` value of the recursive function to fill the nodes:

```
struct tree *BST(int start,int end){
    if(start>end){
        return NULL;
    }
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    bst *root = CreateNode(arr[mid]);
    root->left = BST(start,mid-1);
    //printf("%d\n",root->data);
    root->right = BST(mid+1,end);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Or they could use the return value of their current function, which they  presently ignore.  In which case they wouldn't need the `root` argument.  I think that would probably be a better choice for them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good point ;) edited